# Need assistance in converting osquery queries from regexp_like() to regex_match()

Tags: regex, regexp-like, osquery

I'm currently working with `osquery` and need some help in converting several queries that use `regexp_like()` to the equivalent `regex_match()` syntax. I have over 500 queries, and it's not practical to manually update each one. I am specifically working with ATC tables and need to use these queries in packs.

As an example, I have a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT registry_key, act_timestamp FROM testregistry WHERE regexp_like (registry_key, '(?i)\\REGISTRY\\.*\\Services\\SharedAccess\\Parameters\\FirewallPolicy\\StandardProfile') AND lower(reg_val) = lower('EnableFirewall') AND lower(reg_val_data) = lower('0') AND DATE_STR_FILTER
```

I attempted to convert it by replacing `regexp_like()` with `regex_match()` and adding 0 as the index for the full match:

```
SELECT DISTINCT registry_key, act_timestamp FROM testregistry WHERE regex_match (registry_key, '(?i)\\REGISTRY\\.*\\Services\\SharedAccess\\Parameters\\FirewallPolicy\\StandardProfile', 0) AND lower(reg_val) = lower('EnableFirewall') AND lower(reg_val_data) = lower('0') AND DATE_STR_FILTER
```

However, this results in an **"Invalid syntax"** error.

Could someone provide guidance on the correct way to convert these queries? I appreciate any assistance or insights you can offer.

Comment: Why? If `REGEXP_LIKE` works what's the advantage to changing it?

Comment: @seph If you try out _osquery_, you'll notice that running `SELECT REGEX_MATCH("Seph", "^\w{2}", 0);` will return `Se` but `SELECT REGEXP_LIKE("Seph", "^\w{2}");` will print out `Error: no such function: REGEXP_LIKE`. So I assume that this function was either removed or never available. `REGEX_LIKE()` doesn't exist either.

Comment: Oh, I see now, I was confusing the OP's `regexp_like` with the existing osquery `regex_split`. You are correct, osquery has never had a `regexp_like`, and I wonder where these are from.

Answer (score 1):

I never heard from [osquery](https://osquery.io/) before, so I tried it out.
It's a nice discovery! Thanks!

**The function `regex_match()`** is built to return a value. So if you want
to use it as a condition, you have to compare it with something. Example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM services WHERE REGEX_MATCH(name, "^[Aa]", 0) IS NOT NULL;
```

This will return all services starting with the character `A` or `a`.

Another example to show that you can extract some data from a field and
use it in your output:

```sql
SELECT
  name,
  REGEX_MATCH(name, "^.*?(\d+).*$", 1) AS `number_in_name`
FROM
  services
WHERE
  REGEX_MATCH(name, "^[aAbB]", 0) IS NOT NULL;
```

This will list all services starting with `A` or `B` (case insensitive)
and extract the number in the service name and display it in a new
field called `number_in_name`:

```
+------------------------------+----------------+
| name                         | number_in_name |
+------------------------------+----------------+
| AJRouter                     |                |
| ALG                          |                |
| AppIDSvc                     |                |
| Appinfo                      |                |
| AppMgmt                      |                |
| AppReadiness                 |                |
| AppVClient                   |                |
| AppXSvc                      |                |
| AssignedAccessManagerSvc     |                |
| AudioEndpointBuilder         |                |
| Audiosrv                     |                |
| autotimesvc                  |                |
| AxInstSV                     |                |
| BDESVC                       |                |
| BFE                          |                |
| BITS                         |                |
| Bonjour Service              |                |
| BrokerInfrastructure         |                |
| Browser                      |                |
| BTAGService                  |                |
| BthAvctpSvc                  |                |
| bthserv                      |                |
| AarSvc_23283ec               | 23283          |
| BcastDVRUserService_23283ec  | 23283          |
| BluetoothUserService_23283ec | 23283          |
+------------------------------+----------------+
```

### Regex pattern to convert your SQL queries

The regex pattern, with the `x` (e**x**tended) and `i`
(case-**i**nsensitive) modifiers:

```
/
regexp_like\s*\(
  (?<spacing_begin>\s*)        # Capture the spacing as it could contain indentation.
  (?<field>[\w\.]+|`[\w\.]+`), # The DB field, with the backticks notation also.
  (?<spacing_middle>\s*)       # Capture the indentation.
  (?<pattern>                  # Capture the regex pattern:
    (?<quote>['"])             # Strings can start with single or double quotes.
    (?:\k<quote>{2}|.*?)       # Escaped quote or anything else, in an ungreedy way.
    \k<quote>                  # The closing single or double quote captured before.
  )
  (?<spacing_end>\s*)          # Capture the last indentation.
\)
/gxi
```

Replacement:

```
REGEX_MATCH(${spacing_begin}${field},${spacing_middle}${pattern},${spacing_middle}0${spacing_end}) IS NOT NULL
```

**Test it live here**: https://regex101.com/r/3hMryB/3

I'm using PHP's PCRE engine, as it has the `x` modifier that helps you
write regex patterns on multiple lines, with spaces, indentation and
optional comments.

I used named groups to capture the pieces from your SQL query as they
are more readable than numbers in the replacement string.

It can get tricky to capture strings correctly because they can be
single or double quoted (ex: `'hello'` or `"world"`). And we also
have to handle quotes inside of them. I see that in SQL you have
to double them and not escape them with a backslash
(ex: `"Say ""Hello!"""`).

Be also aware that the `(?i)` modifier to make the pattern
case-insensitive doesn't seem to work with `REGEX_MATCH()`. So this
means that we have to rewrite some of the patterns. This could be
done with some JS or PHP, by using a callback function during the
replacement step. Detecting if `(?i)` is in your pattern and in this
case convert all letters to a range with the lowercase and uppercase
declinations (`z` -> `[zZ]`, `é` -> `[éÉ]`, etc).

I wrote all that in JavaScript and **you can run it directly here**:

```js
/**
 * This function is used to call a specific function callback only once
 * at the time. This is to avoid multiple events such as 'input' to run
 * multiple times and lead to a non-responding browser.
 *
 * @param {function} callback The function to call.
 */
function onlyOnceAtATime(callback) {
  // Keep track of all the running callbacks.
  let runningCallbacks = new Map();

  return function (...args) {
    if (runningCallbacks.has(callback.name)) {
      return;
    }

    runningCallbacks.set(callback.name, true);
    callback(...args);
    runningCallbacks.delete(callback.name);
  };
}

/**
 * Converts a SQL query to replace regexp_like() by regex_match().
 *
 * @param {string} sql The SQL query to convert.
 * @return {string} The new SQL query.
 */
function convertRegexpLikeToRegexMatch(sql) {
  return sql.replace(
    /regexp_like\s*\((?<spacing_begin>\s*)(?<field>[\w\.]+|`[\w\.]+`),(?<spacing_middle>\s*)(?<pattern>(?<quote>['"])(?:\k<quote>{2}|.*?)\k<quote>)(?<spacing_end>\s*)\)/giu,
    (fullMatch, spacingBegin, field, spacingMiddle, pattern, quote, spacingEnd) => {
      const regexpCaseInsensitiveModifier = /\(\?i\)/;
      // The pattern has to potentially be replaced if it contains "(?i)".
      if (pattern.match(regexpCaseInsensitiveModifier)) {
        // 1. Remove this unsupported modifier.
        pattern = pattern.replace(regexpCaseInsensitiveModifier, '');
        // 2. Make all letters case-insensitive.
        pattern = convertToCaseInsensitive(pattern);
      }
      // Return the modified SQL.
      return 'REGEX_MATCH(' + spacingBegin + field + ',' + spacingMiddle +
             pattern + ',' + spacingMiddle + '0' + spacingEnd + ') IS NOT NULL';
    }
  );
}

/**
 * Converts a regex pattern to case-insensitive.
 *
 * @param {string} input The regex pattern to modify.
 * @return {string} The modified regex pattern.
 */
function convertToCaseInsensitive(input) {
  return input.replace(
    // Pattern to find indented code blocks (not in fences).
    /\p{L}/gu,
    // Replacement callback function:
    (letter) => {
      return '[' + letter.toLowerCase() + letter.toUpperCase() + ']';
    }
  );
}

// When the document is ready, attach the event handlers.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const input = document.getElementById("input");
  const output = document.getElementById("output");

  function updateOutput() {
    output.value = convertRegexpLikeToRegexMatch(input.value);
  }
  
  // Each change in the input textarea should update the output textarea.
  input.addEventListener('input', onlyOnceAtATime(updateOutput));
  
  // When clicking in the output textarea, select all the text.
  output.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);
  });
  
  // For the first load, calculate the output.
  updateOutput();
});
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body *, body *:before, body *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
textarea[readonly] {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
```

```html
<h3>Converts <code>regexp_like()</code> to <code>regex_match()</code> and handles the missing <code>(?i)</code> modifier</h3>

<form action="#">
  <div>
    <textarea name="input" id="input"
              cols="80" rows="20"
              placeholder="Paste your SQL queries here">
SELECT DISTINCT registry_key, act_timestamp FROM testregistry WHERE regexp_like (registry_key, '(?i)\\REGISTRY\\.*\\Services\\SharedAccess\\Parameters\\FirewallPolicy\\StandardProfile') AND lower(reg_val) = lower('EnableFirewall') AND lower(reg_val_data) = lower('0') AND DATE_STR_FILTER;

-- Another example with indentation respected during replacement.
SELECT
  registry_key,
  act_timestamp
FROM
  testregistry
WHERE
  REGEXP_LIKE(
    registry_key,
    "^\\[rR][eE]"
  )
  AND LOWER(reg_val) = LOWER('EnableFirewall')
  AND LOWER(reg_val_data) = LOWER('0')
  AND DATE_STR_FILTER;</textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Output:</p>
    <textarea name="output" id="output"
              cols="30" rows="20"
              readonly></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @User0987 Welcome! I'm glad it helped you. The problem took me quite a while to solve it, but it was interesting :-)